# Understanding mathematical concept behind an objective function

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to understand the following expression (which can be called an objective function as well):
${b_t}\left( {\omega ,\rho } \right) = \arg \mathop {\max }\limits_{b \in {\Delta _m}} \quad\prod\limits_{i \in {C_t}\left( {\omega ,\rho } \right)} {\left( {b\cdot{x_i}} \right)} \qquad \qquad \qquad (Eq. 7)$
which is provided in [this scientific article](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/corn-correlation-driven-non-parametric) (page 11). Suppose ${C_t}\left( {\omega ,\rho } \right)$ is $\{ 1,2, \ldots ,n\}$. The components are defined as follows:

- $\omega$: length of time window (Integer and is known)
- $\rho$: correlation coefficient threshold (a real value $-1\le\rho\le1$ and is known)
- $b_t$: vector of weights for the $t$'th day
- $\Delta _m$: a simplex with $m$ components (actually, it demonstrates two constraints:
  $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^m {{b_{ij}}}  = 1$,
  $0 \le {b_{ij}} \le 1$,
  $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}{\rm{   }}$,
  $j \in\{ 1,2, \ldots ,m\}$
  In the above, $b_{ij}$ refers to $j$'th element of $i$'th set of weights.
- $b$: vector of weights with length $m$
- $x_i$: vector of real values with length $m$ (is known)

My question is where we have $\arg \max \prod {} $! The output of $b\cdot{x_i}$ is supposed to be a scalar, consequently, the output of $\prod\limits_{i \in {C_t}\left( {\omega ,\rho } \right)} {\left( {b \cdot {x_i}} \right)} $ is supposed to be a scalar. So, how can we look for $\arg \max$ of a scalar? Furthermore, ${b_t}\left( {\omega ,\rho } \right)$ is supposed to be the vector of weights for $t$'th day, but $\arg \max$ returns an integer index. So, ${b_t}\left( {\omega ,\rho } \right)=index$ expression doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimization variable, a.k.a., decision variable, in this problem is the length m vector $b_i$.

The objective function of a "standard" (single objective) optimization problem must evaluate to a real scalar, and depending on the problem is maximized or minimized, in this case, maximized. We can conclude that 4 > 3. But is (2,4) > (1,5)?  That doesn't make sense. So that is why the objective function must evaluate to s real scalar.

argmax (argmin in the case of minimization) is the optimal value (i.e., argument value) of the optimization variable, which in this case is a length m vector. argmax is short for the argument value at which the maximum of the objective function occurs, subject to (i.e. given) the constraints. So it is the value of the length m vector $b_i$ at which the objective function is maximized, given that $b_i$ satisfies all the constraints.

Comment: Yes, it *"must evaluate to a scalar"*, but assigning the *scalar* to ${b_t}\left( {\omega ,\rho } \right)$ was my point. Ok, that makes sense. So, you mean in the above, the $\arg \max$ term doesn't lead to an index, but a vector with length $m$. But, what's the role of $\prod {}$ here? I mean, **for each** $x_i$ the optimal vector of $b$ can be found through $\max \left( {b \cdot {x_i}} \right)$. Then, I can't realize the role of $\prod {}$ operator up there.

Comment: does the expression $\prod\limits_{i \in {C_t}\left( {\omega ,\rho } \right)} {\left( {b \cdot {x_i}} \right)} $ mean $\left( {b \cdot {x_1}} \right) \times \left( {b \cdot {x_2}} \right) \times  \cdots  \times \left( {b \cdot {x_m}} \right)= scalar \times scalar \times  \cdots  \times scalar$? I don't think so. Because it doesn't make sense with the $\arg \max$ term.

Comment: Here is what I expect: for each ${x_i},i \in \{ 1,2, \ldots ,n\} $ a vector $b_i$ is found, and the value of the objective function is computed through the $\max{b_i\cdot{x_i}}$. Hence, we achieve $n$ different set of $b$s. Then, we choose the $b_j$ which the objective function value gets maximized.

Comment: A bunch of $bx_i$ are multiplied together, that what $\Pi$  means. That product is the objective function. The solution of the optimization problems consists of two things: 1) finding the maximum value of the objective function subject to the constraints, 2) the argmax, which is the length m vector of optimization variables values which achieves that maximum objective value.

Comment: Can you please make a minimal example?

Comment: minimize $x_1^2 + (x_2-1)^2$ subject to $x_1 \ge 0.5, x_2 \ge -1$.  The argmin is (0.5,1), which achieves optimal objective value = 0.25. The concept is basically the same if maximizing instead of minimizing.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the example is quite clear. However, I meant if you could make an example with the objective function that I've provided.

Comment: Let's say $m=n=2$. Then, I guess the objective function can be rewritten as follows: $\max z= (b_1×x_{11} + b_2×x_{12})×(b_1×x_{21}+b_2×x_{22})$. Then, we look for the $b_1$ and $b_2$ that maximizes the expression. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. That combination of $b_1$ and $b_2$ is the argmax, anf the corresponding value of the objective function using those values of $b_1$ and $b_2$ is the optimal objective value.